# nodejs express stops working after couple of day

Tags: node.js, express

After setting up the website with NodeJS and Express it is working fine for a couple of days, but then it stops working. Stop working means that when we send a post request or get request to the backend nothing happens. After sending form there is a session to set then redirect to other page but it stays on the same page. I use express-session and MemoryStor. There is not log or error in npm or in the node console.

**app.js:**

```js
import debug = require('debug');
import express = require('express');
import path = require('path');
import routes from './routes/index';
import test1 from './routes/test1';
import test2 from './routes/test2';
import test3 from './routes/test3';
import helmet = require('helmet');

var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var session = require('express-session');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var MemoryStore = require('memorystore')(session);
var device = require('express-device');
var compression = require('compression');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true})); 
app.use(bodyParser.json());       // to support JSON-encoded bodies
app.use(device.capture({ parseUserAgent: true }));
app.use(express.json());       // to support JSON-encoded bodies
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true })); // to support URL-encoded bodies
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(compression());
app.use(helmet());
app.set('trust proxy', 1);

app.use(session({
    secret: 'test',
    resave: false,
    store: new MemoryStore({
        checkPeriod: 86400000 // prune expired entries every 24h
    }),
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: {
        secure: false, //for https
        maxAge: 60000,
        expires: new Date(Date.now() + (604800000)) //7
    }
}));

Array.prototype.unique = function () {
    var a = this.concat();
    for (var i = 0; i < a.length; ++i) {
        for (var j = i + 1; j < a.length; ++j) {
            if (a[i].id === a[j].id)
                a.splice(j--, 1);
        }
    }

    return a;
};
// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'pug');

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', routes); // 404 error for this line
app.use('/test1', test1);
app.use('/test2', test2);
app.use('/test3', test3);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    var err = new Error('Not Found');
    err['status'] = 404;
    next(err);
});
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    const oldRedirect = res.redirect;
    res.redirect = function (...args) {
        if (req.session) {
            req.session.save(() => Reflect.apply(oldRedirect, this, args));
        } else {
            Reflect.apply(oldRedirect, this, args);
        }
    }
});
// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
    app.use((err: any, req, res, next) => {
        res.status(err['status'] || 500);
        res.render('error', {
            message: err.message,
            error: err
        });
    });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use((err: any, req, res, next) => {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
        message: err.message,
        error: {}
    });
});

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);

var server = app.listen(app.get('port'), function () {
    debug('Express server listening on port ' + server.address().port);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to use process manager. What if the Node.js app crashes? How are you going to ensure it restarts? Process manager can ensure that by keeping it up and running.

PM2 is a production process manager for Node.js applications with a built-in load balancer. It allows you to keep applications alive forever, to reload them without downtime and to facilitate common system admin tasks.

Hope this helps.